# Open file hook to move the cursor to the buffer/file end

Tags: vim

How can i write a hook function that will place the cursor at the end of the file on opening a file.

In elisp, it looks approximately like this,

```
(add-hook 'open-buffer-hook
      (lambda () (end-of-buffer)))
```

In vim, I can open a file and press `:$` to go to the end but i am keen on doing it via a hook.

Comment: Do you want to open one file from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `autocmd` you may hook into `BufReadPost` and execute something like `G$` in normal mode to advance to the last line and the last character.

```
autocmd BufReadPost * :normal G$
```

I used `BufReadPost` to cause this command to run after the file is fully read into the buffer.  The `*` applies this rule to all buffer types, but you could limit it by `FileType` or by filename pattern as well. See `:help autocmd` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

An autocommand seems too much to me.

In your shell,

```
$ vim file +$
```

opens `file` in Vim and jumps to the last line.

In Vim,

```
:edit +$ file
```

opens `file` and jumps to the last line.

This works with other related commands like `:vsplit` or `:tabedit`.

Answer (score 0):

It you just want to open files from the command line, you can use

```
vim +':norm G$' file.txt
```